# In pyspark dataframe I want to count the distinct values based on window

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe like

| plan | name | user_id | dollars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FWE | QRS | 123 | 10 |
| FWE | QRS | 123 | 20 |
| FWE | QRS | 223 | 30 |
| RWE | QRS | 223 | 40 |

[Dataframe screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1nSa.png)

I want to count the number of unique `user_id`s based on partition by plan and name.

I'm expecting output like

| plan | name | user_id | dollars | un_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FWE | QRS | 123 | 10 | 2 |
| FWE | QRS | 123 | 20 | 2 |
| FWE | QRS | 223 | 30 | 1 |
| RWE | QRS | 223 | 40 | 1 |

I want this `un_count` using `withColumn` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('plan', 'name')

df = df.withColumn('un_count', count(col('user_id')).over(window_spec))
```